# d3.Stratify() property 'child' does not exist on type 'unknown'

Tags: angular, d3.js, tree

I'm trying to make a simple tree in D3 using the stratify method. I'm doing it in Angular in my ngOnInit method.

```
  var dataStructure = d3.stratify().id(function(d){return d.child;}).parentId(function(d){return d.parent;})(this.data);
  var treeStructure = d3.tree().size([500,300]);
  var information = treeStructure(dataStructure);
```

The error I'm getting is that there is no property (child) of unknown (d).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same mistake. I tried a family tree with d3js in my angular application. Everything is fine with:

```
private dataStructure = d3.stratify()
.id((d: any= {}) => d.child)
.parentId((d: any= {}) => d.parent)
(this.data);
```